# Тонкости работы Decimal. Ошибка decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: python

Весь день мучился с ошибками в работе, в итоге выяснил, что переменные с типом Decimal выдают такую ошибку в следующем случае. Decimal(a / b * 100), то есть получение процентов. Если а меньше b, то все работает нормально, если a >= b, то появляется вышеназванная ошибка. Кто-нибудь знает, почему так работает?

Comment: Должно работать. Проверьте чему конкретно равны a и b при возникновении ошибки и напишите здесь.

Comment: И какого типа a и b, тоже Decimal?

Comment: спасибо, разобрался, у меня атрибут max_digits=3 в джанго стоял, поэтому проверка не проходила